# What's another idiom/proverb for there is more to something than meets the eye?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, proverbs, proverb-requests

I have to make an idiom/proverb for 'there is more to something than meets the eye' in the context of culture; that often, traditions and customs are just symbolic/representative of bigger things. Could someone help me come up with something that means this?

Comment: None of these capture quite what you describe: *Looks can be deceiving*, *Still waters run deep*, *Don't judge a book by its cover*, *Never judge a person until you've walked a mile in their shoes*, *Don't jump to conclusions*

Comment: So you’re not looking for an existing one- You want to make up a new one?

Comment: yes! but if there is an existing one you could think of, even that would help in figuring out a new one.

Comment: *The paint job don't tell ya what's under the hood.*

Comment: *That little pot of tea’s been steeped in a thousand years of history.*

Comment: *Sometimes a cigar is just a--centuries of western hegemony.*

Comment: *Often, customs and traditions are just the tip of the iceberg.* (No, it's not solely used with negative connotations.)

Comment: These are all extremely helpful! Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 2):

**[Tip of the iceberg](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/tip-of-the-iceberg)** ( Cambridge Dictionary)

> a small, noticeable part of a problem, the total size of which is
>   really much greater:
>
> *These small local protests are just the tip of the iceberg.*